# Pandas dataframe groupby text value that occurs in two columns

Tags: python, pandas, nlp, cluster-computing

My dataframe looks like this:

```python
     v1           v2        distance
0   be          belong      0.666667
4   increase    decrease    0.666667
9   analyze     assay       0.666667
11  bespeak     circulate   0.769231
21  induce      generate    0.800000
24  decrease    delay       0.750000
26  cause       trip        0.666667
27  isolate     distinguish 0.750000
28  give        infect      0.666667
29  result      prove       0.800000
31  describe    explain     0.714286
33  report      circulate   0.666667
36  affect      expose      0.666667
40  explain     intercede   0.705882
41  suppress    restrict    0.833333
```

With `v1` and `v2` being verbs and `distance` is their similarity. I want to create clusters of similar words, based on their appearance in the dataframe.

For example, the word **circulate** appears be similar with both **bespeak** and **report**. So I would like to have a cluster of these 3 words. Groupby doesn't help since they are string values. Can someone help?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

This seems like a graph problem.

You could try to use [`networkx`](https://networkx.org):

```
import networkx as nx

G = nx.from_pandas_edgelist(df, 'v1', 'v2')

clusters = nx.connected_components(G)
```

output:

```
[{'be', 'belong'}, {'delay', 'increase', 'decrease'}, {'analyze', 'assay'},
 {'report', 'bespeak', 'circulate'}, {'induce', 'generate'}, {'trip', 'cause'},
 {'distinguish', 'isolate'}, {'infect', 'give'}, {'prove', 'result'},
 {'intercede', 'describe', 'explain'}, {'affect', 'expose'}, {'restrict', 'suppress'}]
```

As graph:

[image: graph]

Small function to plot the graph in jupyter:

```
def nxplot(G):
    from networkx.drawing.nx_agraph import to_agraph
    A = to_agraph(G)
    A.layout('dot')
    A.draw('/tmp/graph.png')
    from IPython.display import Image
    return Image(filename='/tmp/graph.png')
```

Comment: Hi, thanks, but how can I see the graph in a jupyter notebook? It seems to run without errors, but I can't see anything

Comment: @joasa I used [`graphviz`](https://graphviz.org/doc/info/lang.html) to plot the graph. For a simple graph you can use `nx.draw_networkx(G)`

Comment: Can you please tell me what's the line of code needed to visualize it in graphviz? Cause `nx.draw_network(G)` is giving me a blurry image.

Comment: @joasa this is not a line but a small function, I updated the answer

Comment: Sorry but I do `!pip install pygraphviz` on my jupyter notebook and it gives me an installation error. How did you manage to install and import it?

Comment: @joasa I don't know, this is a bit outside the scope of this question ;)

Answer (score 0):

The following line would select only the rows containing the string `target_string`:

```
rows = df[df.applymap(lambda element: element ==  target_string).any(axis = 1)]
```

Concatenate them and find the unique elements:

```
cluster = pd.concat([rows[['v1', 'v2']]], axis = 1).unique()
```

If you want to find clusters with all the words, repeat this for all the unique elements. An inefficient example:

```
clusters = pd.DataFrame()
for target_string in df.v1.unique():
    rows = df[df.applymap(lambda element: element ==  target_string).any(axis = 1)]
    clusters.append(pd.concat([rows[['v1', 'v2']]], axis = 1).unique())
```