# how to find circulation in dataframe

Tags: python, pandas

my goal is to find if the following df has a 'circulation'

given:

```
df = pd.DataFrame({'From':['USA','UK','France','Italy','Russia','china','Japan','Australia','Russia','Italy'],
                  'to':['UK','France','Italy','Russia','china','Australia','New Zealand','Japan','USA','France']})
df
```

[image]

and if I graph it, it would look like this (eventually, note that the order on the df is different):

```
USA-->UK-->France-->Italy-->Russia-->China-->Australia-->Japan-->Australia
                      |       |
                      |       |
                    France   USA
```

The point is this: You cannot go backward, so Italy cannot go to France and Russia cannot go to USA.

Note: **From** can have multiple **Tos**

How can I find it in pandas so the end result would look like this:
[image]

I can solve it without pandas (I get `df.to_dict('records')` and then iterate to find the circulation and then go back to pandas) but I wish to stay on pandas.

Comment: You cannot go backwards, but as you have a loop, you can go from any point of a loop to any other one, no? Also you explicitly say we can go from Russia to USA, you might want to double check ;)

Comment: Your logic is not fully clear, can you have a look at my answer and comment?

Answer (score 5, accepted):

The logic is not fully clear, however you can approach your problem with a graph.

Your graph is the following:

[image: graph]

Let us consider circulating nodes, those that have more than one destination.

You can obtain this with `networkx`:

```
import networkx as nx

G = nx.from_pandas_edgelist(df, source='From', target='to', create_using=nx.DiGraph)

circulating = {n for n in G if len(list(G.successors(n)))>1}

df['IS_CIRCULATING'] = df['From'].isin(circulating).astype(int)
```

output:

```
        From           to  IS_CIRCULATING
0        USA           UK               0
1         UK       France               0
2     France        Italy               0
3      Italy       Russia               1
4     Russia        china               1
5      china    Australia               0
6      Japan  New Zealand               0
7  Australia        Japan               0
8     Russia          USA               1
9      Italy       France               1
```

With pure pandas:

```
df['IS_CIRCULATING'] = df.groupby('From')['to'].transform('nunique').gt(1).astype(int)
```

Comment: thank you! your answer solved the problem although the graph is a bit off. Think about a starting point USA and you walk from-->to. You can see it goes from Australia to china (in your graph they are separated). anyway, i got the networkx. Would you mind telling what did you use to make this lovely grpah?

Comment: I see, there was a typo in your dataframe Aust**r**alia/Austalia, resulting in the split graph. You can find my code to plot [here](https://stackoverflow.com/a/71065714/16343464).

Comment: you're awesome. Thank you once again!

Answer (score 0):

```
import networkx as nx

gg1=nx.DiGraph(df.apply(tuple,axis=1).tolist())

df11=pd.DataFrame(nx.dfs_edges(gg1),columns=df.columns)

df.merge(df11.assign(IS_CIRCULATING=0), how='left', on=['From','to']).fillna(1)
```

out

```
  From           to  IS_CIRCULATING
0        USA           UK             0.0
1         UK       France             0.0
2     France        Italy             0.0
3      Italy       Russia             0.0
4     Russia        china             0.0
5      china    Australia             0.0
6      Japan  New Zealand             0.0
7  Australia        Japan             0.0
8     Russia          USA             1.0
9      Italy       France             1.0
```