# Using Networkx to Create Pretty Org Chart from Dataframe

Tags: python, pandas, matplotlib, graph, networkx

I have an Excel spreadsheet that has columns for employee name (`Employee`) and their supervisor name (`Supervisor`).

I have the following code that is generating Org Chart based on the link of Employee to Supervisor.

```
import pandas as pd
import networkx as nx
import matplotlib.pyplot as plt
from networkx.drawing.nx_pydot import graphviz_layout

# Load spreadsheet
df = pd.read_excel('input/testing_data.xlsx')

# Create graph
G = nx.from_pandas_edgelist(df, source='Supervisor', target='Employee', create_using=nx.DiGraph)

# Create layout and display
pos = graphviz_layout(G, prog="twopi")
nx.draw(G, pos, with_labels=True, font_size=6)
plt.show()
```

Here is the output of the graph (might have to open in separate page to see detail). Also note that some groups are separate.

[image]

The problem I am having is that the nodes of employees are overlapping and the node does not fully cover the Employee Name. How do I have a display similar to what I have where the nodes cover the employee name and none of the nodes touch another?

I am open to any alternative that would create a similar display (ideally in radial format)

Comment: You can try `dot`/`graphviz` for nice graph generation. See [my answer here](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/71065299/pandas-dataframe-groupby-text-value-that-occurs-in-two-columns/71065714#71065714) for a quick plotting snippet.

Comment: I actually used your solution and it made a [very wide layout](https://i.imgur.com/AwMBT9M.png). I was looking for something more radial to make better use of space.

Comment: There are different layouts. If you put junk in place of `dot` in my snippet you'll get an error with the list of available layouts, give them a try ;)