# Drawing a directed graph from a list of nodes with Python

Tags: python, matplotlib, graph, networkx, bayesian-networks

That's the ending graph that I would like to end up with, but to begin with it would be great to have simply bus late and overslept without considering the alarm on node.

[image]

I would like to know how to draw a directed graph on Python starting from a list of nodes. I know that I have to use networkX but I'm having some troubles;

Let's say that all the nodes from a specific list are linked to another external node, called x, so if I have the list of nodes : `nodes = [1,2,3]`, I will want edges `((1,0),(2,0),(3,0))`; How could I draw then this specific graph?

I got stuck here, basically I have created a directed graph I think, but I don't know how to draw it:

```py
    import networkx as nx
    import matplotlib.pyplot as plt
    
    G = nx.Graph()
    nodes = [1,2,3]
    
    terminal = [0]
    G.add_nodes_from(nodes)
    
    edges = []
    
    for i in range(len(nodes)):
        edges.append((0, nodes[i]))
    
    G.add_edges_from(edges)
    
    H = nx.DiGraph(G)
```

Furthermore, I want to later use it for a Bayesian Network, any suggestions?

Any help will be greatly appreciated

Answer (score 0, accepted):

What about:

```
import networkx as nx
from itertools import product

nodes = [1, 2, 3]
terminal = [0]

G = nx.from_edgelist(product(nodes, terminal), create_using=nx.DiGraph)
```

Resulting graph:

```
nx.draw(G, pos=nx.spring_layout(G), with_labels=True)
```

Output:

[image]

Or with [`graphviz`](https://graphviz.org/):

[image]

Comment: That's great, even though what I am looking for is something more like what you showed with graphviz, could you share the code of it?

Comment: @Kizu I have a small function to interface with graphviz in jupyter, see [here](https://stackoverflow.com/a/71065714/16343464)

Answer (score 0):

You can also directly use packages that deal with Bayesian networks. For instance :

[image]

(pydot is the package used here to interact with graphviz)