# Adding nodes and edges to an existing graph in networkx via dictionaries

Tags: dictionary, networkx

Do you know how to add nodes and edges to an existing graph using dictionaries?

Let's say I have a list of nodes `l = ['a', 'b', 'c']` and a dictionary d such that `d = {'a': ['apple', 'banana'], 'b': ['orange']}`.

How can I implement this addition to an existing  graph with networkx such that apple and banana will be two different nodes each linked to a and orange will be linked to b?

I already have a,b,c connected to a node z.

This is how I create the initial graph

```
import networkx as nx
from itertools import product

G = nx.from_edgelist(product(l, z), create_using=nx.DiGraph)
```

How can I modify it?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You need to rework your dictionary:

```py
import networkx as nx
from itertools import product

l = ['a', 'b', 'c']
d = {'a': ['apple', 'banana'], 'b': ['orange']}

G = nx.from_edgelist(product('z', l), create_using=nx.DiGraph)

G.add_edges_from([(n1, n2) for n1, l in d.items() for n2 in l])
```

Output:

[image]

Intermediate list comprehension:

```py
[(n1, n2) for n1, l in d.items() for n2 in l]
# [('a', 'apple'), ('a', 'banana'), ('b', 'orange')]
```

##### reversed order

```
G = nx.from_edgelist(product(l, 'z'), create_using=nx.DiGraph)

G.add_edges_from([(n2, n1) for n1, l in d.items() for n2 in l])
```

Output:

[image]

Comment: Isn't it possible to just add the node and edges? Because in that way I'm basically creating a new graph no? and the feature z is not present anymore in the graph nor in the dictionary

Comment: Yes, I was updating the answer ;)

Comment: @Kizu note that you didn't specify the direction of your edges, I picked one arbitrarily (z->a->apple). Reverse the order of the nodes in `product` and the list comprehension if needed ;)

Comment: It works!! I've another question, how could I see the output like you do?

Comment: check my other answer [here](https://stackoverflow.com/a/71065714/16343464)

Comment: Hey, I was looking at your answer and I managed to install graphviz and use your function, but on spyder how can I actually see the graph? Because I think it gets created but not printed

Comment: Let us [continue this discussion in chat](https://chat.stackoverflow.com/rooms/252327/discussion-between-kizu-and-mozway).

Comment: I couldn't say for spyder, I used jupyter here. You can also find the graph in your temporary folder (make sure to adapt the path depending on your OS) ;)