# Network graph for plotting value counts in pandas df

Tags: python, pandas, count, networkx

I have a huge dataset which I have sliced by years, so I have seperate dataframes for every year.
Now every year, the `value_counts` of column `label` is different.

Suppose for `df_2020`, it is:

```
label
patch               622
minor               289
major.minor         181
major.patch.minor   175
major               150
patch.minor         144
major.patch         95
pre                 53
dev                 11
minor.pre           11
major.pre           11
patch.minor.pre     10
patch.pre           7
major.minor.pre     6
pre.dev             6
minor.dev           5
minor.pre.dev       4
patch.minor.dev.    3
major.patch.minor.dev 4
```

I want to create a network graph that splits the labels by `.` and calculates which labels occur together. So for example from the value_counts above, the line between `pre` and `dev` should have 6, and same for the other labels.

I am a bit new to `networkx` so I am not sure how can I achieve this. Any help would be appreciated.

Comment: I'm assuming here that the `df_2020` is not shown and that the Series you show in the question is `s = df_2020['label'].value_counts()`

Comment: Yes, that's absolutely correct. The output shown here is just the `value_counts()`

Comment: For `major.patch.minor.dev  4`. Do you want 3 edges : major->patch, patch->minor, minor->dev and group by edges and sum the count? For example for minor->dev, the count could be 5 + 3 + 4. And what about single node (row without dot in name)

Comment: What I had in mind was actually a self-loop for the single nodes( which I was looking into), and for the rest summation of how they all occur. Yes, as you mentioned the count for minor.dev is correct. I am a bit unsure about the 3 edges scenario, i am not sure how the output will actually look like

Comment: Just explode each pair into as many rows as needed and duplicate the value. If you don't do that what does it mean `major.patch.minor.dev 4`? major -> patch = 4 or path -> minor = 4 or minor -> dev = 4 ? Which one do you want to take account?

Comment: So that particular label means that a version upgraded in all four areas, on comparing with the previous version. For such case, major.minor , patch.minor and minor.dev: all will be 4

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You can use [`str.extract`](https://pandas.pydata.org/docs/reference/api/pandas.Series.str.extract.html) to get the last pair of `x.y` values, then pass it to [`networkx.from_pandas_edgelist](https://networkx.org/documentation/stable/reference/generated/networkx.convert_matrix.from_pandas_edgelist.html):

```
import networkx as nx

# s = df_2020['label'].value_counts()

tmp = (
 s.reset_index(name='label')
  .sort_values(by='index', key=lambda s: s.str.count('.'))
  .pipe(lambda d: d.join(d['index'].str.extract(r'(?:([^.]+).)?(\b[^.]+)$')))
  .drop_duplicates(subset=[0, 1])
)

G = nx.from_pandas_edgelist(tmp, source=0, target=1,
                            create_using=nx.DiGraph, edge_attr='label')

# remove "nan" as node
G.remove_node(np.nan)
```

Resulting graph:

[image: networkx graph]

`tmp` DataFrame:

```
          index  label      0      1
7           pre     53    NaN    pre
8           dev     11    NaN    dev
0         patch    622    NaN  patch
1         minor    289    NaN  minor
4         major    150    NaN  major
14      pre.dev      6    pre    dev
15    minor.dev      5  minor    dev
12    patch.pre      7  patch    pre
10    major.pre     11  major    pre
9     minor.pre     11  minor    pre
6   major.patch     95  major  patch
5   patch.minor    144  patch  minor
2   major.minor    181  major  minor
```

##### `networkx` builtin graph

Here without NaN

```
pos = nx.spring_layout(G)
nx.draw(G, pos, with_labels=True, node_size=3000)
nx.draw_networkx_edge_labels(G, pos, edge_labels=nx.get_edge_attributes(G, 'label'))
```

Output:

[image]

###### with self-loops:

```
import networkx as nx

tmp = (
 s.reset_index(name='label')
  .sort_values(by='index', key=lambda s: s.str.count('.'))
  .pipe(lambda d: d.join(d['index'].str.extract(r'(?:([^.]+).)?(\b[^.]+)$').bfill(axis=1)))
  .drop_duplicates(subset=[0, 1])
)

G = nx.from_pandas_edgelist(tmp, source=0, target=1,
                            create_using=nx.DiGraph, edge_attr='label')
```

###### Graph:

dot version:

[image]

networkx/matplotlib version:

[image]

Comment: `tmp` needs to be defined before right? In my case the code you wrote above needs to work on the `df_2020` label column. Also I don't see a display graph option in the first code, sorry I am bit confused.

Comment: No, sorry I forgot to mention, the input is your `value_counts` Series, here named **`s`**. And the first graph is not produced by the code (it's done with another package, I just showed it for illustration, see [here](https://stackoverflow.com/a/71065714/16343464)). The first code only produces the networkx graph object **`G`**.

Comment: Ahh I understood now thanks, I got confused seeing the other graph. I had another doubt, it runs fine however I get this text: `{('pre', 'dev'): Text(-0.5472320304366987, 0.39834094317749213, '6'),` before the graph, I am afraid I don't know why, since I didn't modify anything in the code other than the inputs.

Comment: This is return of the `nx.draw`/`nx.draw_networkx_edge_labels` commands, you can ignore it (or add a `;` in the end of the line if you use jupyter)

Comment: One note while you're here, as you have several occurrences of some combinations (e.g. `minor.dev`, I used the one with the lesser number of dots `minor.dev` > `patch.minor.dev` > `major.patch.minor.dev`. You can change this logic if wanted (or aggregate if needed).

Comment: For some reason, I still see the nan in my graph. i was getting a .str accessor error, so essentially I did this: `s = df_2020['label'].astype(str).value_counts().dropna()`, and then the code as mentioned, but the nan persists

Comment: @BrieMerryWeather the thing is that I'm not sure of the exact expected output ;) Why don't you provide a schematic of the expected graph? For the NaN, you can also remove it before: `tmp = tmp.dropna(subset=[0, 1])`. Regarding self-loops and considering all `x.y.z` it's also doable but I need to know exactly what you want.

Comment: I'll check tomorrow ;)

Comment: The graph in the dot version is exactly the output I had in mind, i guess networkx hides the count above?

Comment: Btw, please do check this again, if possible, if there is a way I could get the count on the self-loops?

Comment: @Brie I know with dot, but not with networkx builtin graph, sorry :/

Comment: Ahh, is there a way to incorporate dot in pandas?

Comment: Yes, I gave you the link for [networkx graph with dot](https://stackoverflow.com/a/71065714/16343464) before (there are other ways) ;)