# How can I create a decision tree-like graph in Python?

Tags: pandas, binary-search-tree, decision-tree

I have a Pandas dataframe with some columns, such as:

```
product      color      type
A            blue       2
A            red        3
A            red        1
B            red        1
B            red        2
B            green      5
C            yellow     1
C            yellow     2
C            blue       3
.
.
.
```

I wanted to create a scheme looking like a decision tree, showing all the possibilities with have with the columns and values we see. Something like this:

```
       A                    B                   C
  blue  red            red    green       yellow  blue
  1  2   3            1  2      5         1   2     3
```

But with arrows connecting the values, A would be connected with blue and red, that would be connected to 1, 2 and 3, and so on. Just like the way we visualize a Decision Tree, but I don't want to create a statistical model, only show the possibilities available and perhaps the number of observations for each possibility.

Is that possible? I searched for all types of terms, but couldn't find anything even close to that.

I thought about running a Machine Learning model and then plotting, but I don't think that would get what I want, because it would explore things by Information Gain and I want to show everything.

Comment: Separate generating the tree from displaying it.  I'd recommend a random forest from Scikit Learn to generate the tree and graphviz/dot or Plant UML to display it.

Answer (score 1):

You could use [`networkx`](https://networkx.org/) to build a directed graph:

```
from itertools import pairwise
import networkx as nx

G = nx.from_edgelist((edge for row in df.to_numpy()
                      for edge in pairwise(row)),
                     create_using=nx.DiGraph
                    )
```

Graph (after rendering by `graphviz`):

[image]

Code to plot (exports an image and outputs in jupyter), see [here](https://stackoverflow.com/a/71065714/16343464):

```
def nxplot(G):
    from networkx.drawing.nx_agraph import to_agraph
    A = to_agraph(G)
    A.layout('dot')
    A.draw('/tmp/graph.png')
    from IPython.display import Image
    return Image(filename='/tmp/graph.png')

nxplot(G)
```