# Dynamic pandas dataframe

Tags: python, pandas

I have the following df :

```
pd.DataFrame(data={
'SON' : ['Category1','Category2','Category3','Category4','Category5','Category6','Category7'],
'PARENT' : [None,'Category1','Category1','Category2','Category4','Category4','Category6']})
```

This df summarizes which category is a sub-category of a parent category. For example, Category2 is a sub-category of Category1. Similarly, Category3 is a sub-category of Category1. Category4 is a sub-category of Category2, Category5 is a sub-category of Category4, and so on.

I'd like a function that could summarize these informations in a dataframe, and link all the sub-categories together. For example, thanks to the previous df, we know that Category5 is a sub-category of Category4, Category4 is a sub-category of Category2, and Category2 is a sub-category of Category1. I'd like to have the information on the same row, where each column contains the categories of the hierarchy in descending order of size.

In the example of that last df, I'd like the following output:

```
pd.DataFrame(data={
    'Biggest_category' : ['Category1','Category1','Category1'],
    'Second_Biggest_category': ['Category2','Category2','Category3'],
    'Third_Biggest_category': ['Category4','Category4',[]],
    'Fourth_Biggest_category': ['Category5','Category6',[]],
    'Fifth_Biggest_category': [[],'Category7',[]]
})
```

Can someone helps me please? I have tried many things but nothing really work as I would like.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

What you want is to build a graph of your edges and to get the shortest path between each pair of root and leaf for each connected subgraph. This is not easily done with pandas alone.

You can however achieve this with [`networkx`](https://networkx.org):

```
# pip install networkx
import networkx as nx

# set up graph
G = nx.from_pandas_edgelist(df.dropna(subset=['SON', 'PARENT']),
                            source='PARENT', target='SON',
                            create_using=nx.DiGraph)

# extract roots and leafs
roots  = {n for n, d in G.in_degree() if d==0}
leafs = {n for n, d in G.out_degree() if d==0}

# for each subgraph, get shortest path between each pair of root/leaf
out = pd.DataFrame([nx.shortest_path(G, root, leaf)
                    for g in nx.weakly_connected_components(G)
                    for root in roots&g for leaf in leafs&g])
```

Output:

```
           0          1          2          3          4
0  Category1  Category2  Category4  Category5       None
1  Category1  Category2  Category4  Category6  Category7
2  Category1  Category3       None       None       None
```

Your graph:

[image: networkx graph]

Comment: Thank you A LOT !! This is exactly what I was looking for. Just a question, how do  you display the graph? I'm not used to this

Comment: I use a separate code for that, [see here](https://stackoverflow.com/a/76155401/16343464).

Comment: Yo, I have found a problem on my old dataframe which had to resume which category is a sub-category of a parent category. Could you help me on that https://stackoverflow.com/questions/76530115/create-a-hierarchy-between-categories please? I'm a bit desesperate...

Comment: @Mop I just answered ;)

Comment: Yeh I just saw that, thank you a lot !! I'm just a bit confused because it returns the good result (each son has the good parent), but now I'm trying to link that new answer to the old answer you gave me on that post. And I have some trouble to do that. I think it's due to the fact that I have to get a df from the dictionary first, and then find a solution for Category4 having 2 parents on the same column. Could you maybe help me with that aswell?

Comment: I'm not sure I follow, in the question here you want to convert an edge list into a 2D matrix of paths. In the other question, you converted paths into an edgelist. They are more or less the opposite of each other. What exactly do you want to do now?

Comment: I will try my best to explain. So in my problem, I have a df with TONS of rows which has exactly the same form than the pandas_test df I gave in the other question. So my goal is to resume which category is a sub-category, which one is parent etc... Then, when I have all these informations, I want to get like a tree, like you gave me in the question here. I think I have to do it in 2 separate steps, because my really first dataframe has tons of rows

Comment: Well, I just miss read your last answer on the other question (or maybe you did an edit?). You completely answer it, thank you A LOT. I will try on my real data, I'll let you know

Comment: I'm sorry to bother you again, but I'm using your code on a 3184 rows pandas dataframe. (So I have 3184 rows telling me which category is the parent of an another category, like : Leather is a subcategory of Clothing, etc...). But after using your function with networkx, I have at the end only 2 rows and I can't find why, could you maybe know?

Comment: Not without the data, can you provide it (eventually anonymized) ;)

Comment: I'd like to give you the data anonymized, but how can I do it for 3184 rows? Is there a way to send a .csv on stack overflow? I'm asking that because when I'm trying your function on a 20 or 30 rows (among the 3184 rows), it seems your function is working. So the problem is among the 3K+ rows, somewhere ^^' (again, thanks for your time)

Comment: Maybe a pastebin?

Comment: I just found a dataframe of 20 rows where I have the problem. I anonymized that and send to you

Comment: test_pd=pd.DataFrame(data={
'SON' : ['Cat1','Cat2','Cat2','Cat2','Cat2','Cat2','Cat2','Cat2','Cat2','Cat3','Cat3','Cat3','Cat3','Cat3','Cat3','Cat3','Cat3','Cat4','Cat4','Cat4'],
'PARENT' : ['Cat4','Cat1','Cat5','Cat3','Cat6','Cat4','Cat7','Cat8','Cat9','Cat1','Cat6','Cat5','Cat9','Cat7','Cat10','Cat4','Cat8','Cat3','Cat5','Cat11']})

Comment: When I try your code on this dataframe, I have some mistakes. For example, Cat6 is only the parent of Cat2 (and I don't have Cat3 son of Cat6 swell, as it should be)

Comment: Your graph is circular, which means a parent can have a child being its own ancestor, how do you want to handle that without ambiguity?

Comment: Oh yeh I didn't notice that, Cat3 is the son of Cat4 but Cat4 is the son of Cat3 you right. This should not happened and idk why it's happening, I will look at that. Thank you ! (I will let you know ;) )

Comment: You also have several paths between 2 nodes: for instance `Cat4 -> Cat2` and `Cat4 -> Cat1 -> Cat3 -> Cat2`. [Here is an image](https://i.stack.imgur.com/tkzLg.png). I am using the shortest path in my code (you could use [all paths](https://networkx.org/documentation/stable/reference/algorithms/generated/networkx.algorithms.simple_paths.all_simple_paths.html) if you want).

Comment: No I think I need shortest_path aswell. I have now this dataframe test_pd=pd.DataFrame(data={
'SON' : ['Cat1','Cat2','Cat2','Cat2','Cat2','Cat2','Cat2','Cat2','Cat2','Cat3','Cat3','Cat3','Cat3','Cat3','Cat3','Cat3','Cat3','Cat4','Cat4','Cat4'],
'PARENT' : ['CatA','Cat1','Cat5','Cat3','Cat6','CatA','Cat7','Cat8','Cat9','Cat1','Cat6','Cat5','Cat9','Cat7','Cat10','CatA','Cat8','Cat3','Cat5','Cat11']})
I don't think the graph is circular here, but again it's not working at it should be (for example, I think Cat5 should be the parent of Cat3 aswell)

Comment: Oh, is Cat3 not the son of Cat5 because of that shortest_path? I'm not sure

Comment: In my code I extract roots and leafs, in this example those are `{'Cat10', 'Cat11', 'Cat5', 'Cat6', 'Cat7', 'Cat8', 'Cat9'}` and  `{'Cat2'}`. Thus `Cat3` can only be part of a path, not a terminal node. Because there is a direct path between `Cat5` and `Cat2`, `Cat3` is not used. You can change the logic the way you want, but given the original question this made the most sense ;)

Comment: Ok so it seems the problem is : more I have rows which describing which cat is a parent and which one is a son, more I have the probability to get that issue, when a category is finally not a root or a leaf, but only a part of a path. That's maybe why when I have 3184 rows of son/parent informations, I finally end with 2 rows of complete hierarchy with your code. It's definitely not what I'm looking for, but I don't really know how to solve it...

Comment: Maybe a way to do it is to not consider a row when this row is a direct path between 2 Cat which ignore another Cat which should be between these 2 Cats? I'm not sure to know how to do that, and I'm not even sure it is the solution. What do you think?

Comment: Well, you have to think of the problem you are trying to solve. Discuss this with your colleagues and come up with a strategy. I cannot make the decision for you ;) Feel free to open a new question and let me know when this is the case

Comment: Well I'm the only one working on that project and I have tons of trouble ahah ^^' But I will find a solution :) I just changed your code to consider all nodes as potential leaf nodes and I think I solved that problem, but I have another one since I have only one value in the column 0 of out.

Comment: Just a last thing : I'd like to thank you again for all the time you spend to help me, that was really helpful and not everyone is doing that, so yeh god bless you man !