# Python grouping numbers based on thresholds

Tags: python-3.x, list, numpy

I have 4 points indexed by 0,1,2 and 3 which all have relationships with each other which can be captured by a network or a 2d array like below. I want to group the numbers together based on a threshold such that if the edges exceed a threshold value then the points are grouped together.

```
import numpy as np

np.array([[1.0, 0.2, 0.3, 0.4],
          [0.2, 1.0, 0.7, 0.5],
          [0.3, 0.7, 1.0, 0.2],
          [0.4, 0.5, 0.2, 1.0]])
```

With the example above at different thresholds my results will be:

```
threshold = 0.6
result = [[0], [1,2], [3]]  
#node 0 and 3 connections are all less than the threshold but
#nodes 1 and 2 have an edge of 0.7 which is greater than the threshold.

threshold = 0.8
result = [[0],[1],[2],[3]]

threshold = 0.1

result = [[0,1,2,3]]
```

I want to build a function that can do this for an arbitrary threshold with an arbitrary N x N matrix. All edges are between `0` and `1.0`. The diagonal will always be `1.0` and the matrix will always be symmetric just like in the example.

Comment: How do you compute the distance? Please break down the computation for `threshold = 0.6` for clarity

Comment: @mozway added the explanation

Comment: In your case for `threshold = 0.6`, you group the nodes 1, 2 together because there are values greater than the threshold . But in case for  `threshold = 0.1`, every node have value greater than threshold , why not group them together but separate the nodes ?

Comment: Did you interchange threshold 0.8 and 0.1?

Comment: @HMH1013 you're right I mixed up 0.8 and 0.1. I've corrected it now.

Comment: @Onyambu you're right I mixed up 0.8 and 0.1. I've corrected it now.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The is a graph problem, so you can build a weighted graph with [`networkx`](https://networkx.org), filter the edges with a weight above threshold, and determine the [`connected_components`](https://networkx.org/documentation/stable/reference/algorithms/generated/networkx.algorithms.components.connected_components.html):

```
import networkx as nx

a = np.array([[1.0, 0.2, 0.3, 0.4],
              [0.2, 1.0, 0.7, 0.5],
              [0.3, 0.7, 1.0, 0.2],
              [0.4, 0.5, 0.2, 1.0]])

G = nx.from_numpy_array(a)

def connected_thresh(G, thresh=0):
    keep = [(u,v) for (u,v,d) in G.edges(data=True)
            if d['weight']>thresh]
    H = G.edge_subgraph(keep)
    return list(nx.connected_components(H))

connected_thresh(G, 0.1)
# [{0, 1, 2, 3}]

connected_thresh(G, 0.6)
# [{0}, {1, 2}, {3}]

connected_thresh(G, 0.8)
# [{0}, {1}, {2}, {3}]
```

Your graph:

[image: connected components from numpy weight matrix]

##### pre-filtering the edges in [numpy](/questions/tagged/numpy)

If you have a large array as input and many edges to remove, it might be more efficient to pre-process it with numpy:

```
import networkx as nx

out = list(nx.connected_components(nx.from_numpy_array(a>0.6)))
```

Output: `[{0}, {1, 2}, {3}]`

Graph:

[image]

Comment: thanks mozway, the visual from networkx is super cool. Is there a way to get this in pure numpy?

Comment: The visualization is not default `networkx` [I'm further using `graphviz` to produce it](https://stackoverflow.com/a/76155401/16343464). I don't think you can do this efficiently in pure numpy, you would have to write a function to find the connected components.

Comment: Well, you could pre-filter the edges in numpy and still use `networkx`'s `connected_components`. I'll add an example.